# Motorola ICS R2 Basis Connection Example needed for TI 2540

Tags: motorola, bluetooth-lowenergy

This post is a follow up on 
[Android 4.0.4 BLE API, BroadCom - Motorola](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272310/android-4-0-4-ble-api-broadcom-motorola)

I have decided to give Motorola ICS R2 API a chance, Because I have seen alot of postes here that it should work with TI BLE chips.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360468/motorola-bluetooth-low-energy-api-ics-r2-proper-reconnect

and

[Disconnect Callback in Motorola's ICS Bluetooth Low Energy API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331065/disconnect-callback-in-motorolas-ics-bluetooth-low-energy-api?rq=1)

But my main problem is, I cant use the Profile sample  - besause it uses som ekstra on the BluetoothDevice object as
BluetoothDevice.ACTION_GATT and BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_GATT. 
What do I miss here ?

Basis how  do u connect in the first place ?

I have remembered permissions and so on - and I know I need to use the rigth Uuoid for the Serice on out TI BLE device.

What do I need for to compile the Profile sample ? I

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this post can be seen in

[Android 4.0.4 BLE API, BroadCom - Motorola](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272310/android-4-0-4-ble-api-broadcom-motorola)

Thanks to 
PeterVanPansen.